# Fancybox 2 Dynamic Width Based on Content Size

Tags: jquery, iframe, dynamic, fancybox, sizing

I've got an IFrame being opened via Fancybox 2 that plays a video:

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox-video" href="/user/intro-file.cfm" rel="file_name" title="View Video">File Name</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.fancybox-video").fancybox({
    scrolling   : 'no', 
    type        : 'iframe', 
    helpers     : { 
        title: null 
    }
});
```

The video is user-uploaded, so I don't know the size. I will be setting a maxHeight and maxWidth on the Fancybox eventually, but I've removed them for easier troubleshooting.

How can I set the width of the Fancybox based on the content? With my test file, which is around 400px wide, the fancybox itself is being set to 830/800px wide (the outer and inner widths): [screencap of too-wide fancybox http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/3872/fancyboxwidth.png](http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/3872/fancyboxwidth.png)

autoSize and fitToView have no effect. There's no CSS or code on the IFrame page that is setting a default width. If I force a width in the Fancybox code it works, but since my content is dynamic, it won't work for the live system.

I also tried adapting a function from another question asking about height resizing, but it didn't work either:

```
beforeShow  : function() { 
    $('.fancybox-iframe').load(function() { 
        $('.fancybox-inner').width($(this).contents().find('body').width()); 
    }); 
}
```

Edit: Added the code of the IFrame page I'm trying to load into the Fancybox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <cfoutput>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jwplayer.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'> 
                var max_video_width = 924;
                jwplayer("preview").setup({
                    flashplayer: "/VideoPlayer/player.swf",
                    controlbar: "bottom",
                    file: "/videos/file_name",
                    stretching: 'file_name',
                    autostart: true,
                    events: {
                        onMeta: function(event) {
                            if (get_meta) {
                                if(event.metadata.width != undefined && event.metadata.height != undefined) {
                                    get_meta = false;
                                    if (event.metadata.width > max_video_width) {
                                        var new_height = (max_video_width / (event.metadata.width / event.metadata.height))  
                                        jwplayer("preview").resize(max_video_width,new_height);
                                        jwplayer("preview").stop();
                                        $('##preview_wrapper').width(max_video_width).height(new_height);
                                    } 
                                    else {
                                        jwplayer("preview").resize(event.metadata.width,event.metadata.height);
                                        jwplayer("preview").stop();
                                        $('##preview_wrapper').width(event.metadata.width).height(event.metadata.height);
                                    }
                                    $('.loading-video').slideUp('fast',function(){$('.loading-video').remove()});
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </cfoutput>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the content of that `Iframe` from the same domain?

Comment: `The video is user-uploaded, so I don't know the size` ... does the video have at least a selector that you can identify? .... does the `intro-file.cfm` have a common html structure or does it vary from user to user? ... you should show the rendered html code of `intro-file.cfm` in that case.

Comment: This `$(this).contents().find('body').width()` will never work because `body` will always render at 100% width of the browser or the iframe that contains it, unless you have set specific css dimensions to the tag.

Comment: @Zuul: Yes, it's in the same domain - same folder on the domain even.

Comment: @JFK: The intro-file.cfm does have a common HTML structure. I've added the code for the intro-file.cfm page to my question. Thanks for the clarification on the body.width attempt as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your `intro-file.cfm` file makes things clearer.

If your code inside the file is working fine, I think that you could get the dimensions from the `preview_wrapper` container.

Just two questions:

- if you are using `$` ... in `$('.loading-video').slideUp()` for instance, shouldn't you be including the `jquery.js` file inside your `intro-file.cfm` file?
- is this double `##` before the selector in `$('##preview_wrapper').width()` correct?

Assuming that everything is working fine, then try including in your fancybox script:

```
  scrolling: "no", // optional to avoid scrollbars inside fancybox
  beforeShow: function(){
   this.width = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#preview_wrapper').width();
   this.height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#preview_wrapper').height();
  }
```

... to get the dimensions from the player's wrapper.

Comment: #1 - The jquery is actually being included via a cfinclude, I just omitted it as irrelevant for the purposes of my question. #2 - It's correct because I'm coding in ColdFusion which uses # as a special character. Your code works perfectly! Thanks for helping me work through this.

Comment: One note for anyone looking at this is the future - I ended up adding a bit of padding to the calculated height/width since the white Fancybox border wasn't quite the same all the way around my player: this.width = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#preview_wrapper').width() + 15;

Comment: Nice. Would have been nice if I had found that one in my search!

Answer (score 1):

Iframe width is currently not calculated. Maybe you could set width/height for each iframe like this - http://jsfiddle.net/vVKMF/

Comment: I did see that in my search, but I'm not sure how it applies to my situation. I could set the default height/width on the iframe, but then how would I calculate it based on the content in the Fancybox function?

Answer (score -1):

add `autoSize` to :

```
$("a.fancybox-video").fancybox({
    scrolling   : 'no', 
    type        : 'iframe',
    autoSize    : true, 
    helpers     : { 
        title: null 
    }
});
```

or :

```
fitToView  : true,
```

Comment: Neither of those options are in the v2 documentation: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: @shimmoril try `autoSize:true,`

Comment: @shimmoril or `fitToView : true,`

Comment: From my original question: "autoSize and fitToView have no effect."